# How to use other objc function's variable? (Long Press & Add a Button)

Tags: objective-c, swift, view, uibutton

**Is there any way to use other objc function's variable? Here is the scenario: When I long-press on some point of the view, then menu items come up, and when I press Add button, then I want to create a circle button on that position**

```
//Menu Items
@objc func longPressForView(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) -> CGPoint {
    if sender.state == .began {
        let menu = UIMenuController.shared
        becomeFirstResponder()

        let menuItemAdd = UIMenuItem(title: "Add", action: #selector(addCircleMenuItemAction))
        let menuItemDelete = UIMenuItem(title: "Delete", action: #selector(handleMenuItemAction))
        menu.menuItems = [menuItemAdd, menuItemDelete]

        let location = sender.location(in: sender.view)
        let menuLocation = CGRect(x: location.x, y: location.y, width: 0, height: 0)
        menu.showMenu(from: sender.view!, rect: menuLocation)

        //I tried to return this location but I don't know how to use it
        return location
    }

}
//Click Menu Items' Add Button to add a circle on that position.
@objc func addCircleMenuItemAction() {

    let longPressedlocation = longPressForView(sender: )

    print("Add item tapped")

    view.addSubview(addCircle)
    addCircle.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(circleAddDefaultSize/2)
    addCircle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addCircle.backgroundColor = .black

    //Here is where I want to use the location to add a circle 
    addCircle.frame = CGRect(origin: longPressedlocation?????, size: CGSize(width: circleAddDefaultSize,height: circleAddDefaultSize))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a global variable and use that inside both functions, something like this

```
    //Menu Items
var location: CGPoint

@objc func longPressForView(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) -> CGPoint {
    if sender.state == .began {
        let menu = UIMenuController.shared
        becomeFirstResponder()

        let menuItemAdd = UIMenuItem(title: "Add", action: #selector(addCircleMenuItemAction))
        let menuItemDelete = UIMenuItem(title: "Delete", action: #selector(handleMenuItemAction))
        menu.menuItems = [menuItemAdd, menuItemDelete]

        let location = sender.location(in: sender.view)
        let menuLocation = CGRect(x: location.x, y: location.y, width: 0, height: 0)
        menu.showMenu(from: sender.view!, rect: menuLocation)

        //I tried to return this location but I don't know how to use it
        self.location = location
        return location
    }
}
@objc func addCircleMenuItemAction() {

    print("Add item tapped")

    view.addSubview(addCircle)
    addCircle.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(circleAddDefaultSize/2)
    addCircle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addCircle.backgroundColor = .black

    //Here is where I want to use the location to add a circle 
    addCircle.frame = CGRect(origin: self.location, size: CGSize(width: circleAddDefaultSize,height: circleAddDefaultSize))
}
```

the problem with your code is, when you long-press the view, the longPressForView gets executed and when you hit the button, it gets executed again inside the function: `let longPressedlocation = longPressForView(sender: )`, in this line. so the output won't be the same.